# Dynamically add new array to existing object array React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I am getting the value of id and quantity during the click button. I want add a new array inside the object array. Below is the code

```
adddata =(d,v) => {

    const product = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

    product.push({
                   product_id:d,    
                   cart_quantity:v
            });
        }
console.log(product);


<button value={this.state.quantity} className="btn" onClick={adddata} data-id={item.product_id}>Add to cart</button>
```

The only issue with this implementation is that. it replacing the new value with an existing one. I want to merge it dynamically every time click on the button.

Please help

Comment: why are you using `for loop`?

Comment: please advice best way to do this

Comment: When the addData method is called, It's setting the array to an empty array. That's why you can't get all the data but just the current data

Comment: I assume that you have the array in state, you should `push` the value to that array and if you insist on creating a new array then you can probably use spread operators like `stateArray = [ ...stateArray, ...newArray ]`. And you don't need for loop if you are only pushing one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the variable `product` inside the function, So each time when you execute the function, It will be reinitialized.

**Use Global Variable / State**

```js
// global
const product = [];

addData =(d,v) => {

    // I removed the loop because it's useless here.

    product.push({
       product_id:d,    
       cart_quantity:v
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I just tried this and it's working for me. thank you for the help.